# Prove finite dimensionality of dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space.  Then $V^*$ is finite dimensional as well.

I set up the proof as follows:  Let $\dim{(V)}=n.$  Then there exists a basis, $B=\{v_1, ...,v_n\}$.  Now assume $V^*$ is not finite dimensional.  Then there exists a basis $B^*=\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n, f_{n+1},...\}$ for $V^*$.  Let $f_i(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker Delta, and let $v=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jv_j}$.  Then for $i=1..n,$
$$f_i(v)=f_i\left(\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jv_j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n{f_i(a_jv_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jf_i(v_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_j\delta_{ij}}=a_i  $$
Now, take $i=n+1.$
$$f_{n+1}(v)=f_{n+1}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jv_j}\right)=\sum_{j=1}^n{f_{n+1}(a_jv_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_jf_{n+1}(v_j)}=\sum_{j=1}^n{a_j\delta_{(n+1)j}}=0  $$

This means that our basis for $V^*$, 
$$B^*=\{f_1, ..., f_n, f_{n+1},...\}=\{f_1,...,f_n, 0,0,...\}=\{f_1, ...,f_n\}$$
Therefore, since $B^*$ is a basis for $V^*$, $V^*$ is finite dimensional, and even better, $ \dim{(V^*)}=n$

Does this proof work for the finite dimensionality of $V^*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But the 'infinite basis' you supposed existed might not be the one that sends $v_1$ to $1$ and so on.

To prove all this you need to do is to see that  $$ \{ T : V \to K \text{ such that T is linear} \}$$ is isomorphic to the matrixes of $K$. Or in others words that given any basis $B$ of $V$ and a basis $B'$ of $K$ the function $$g(T) = |T|_{BB'}$$ is an isomorphism.